Не могу сделать дамп БД в Workbench
Всем доброго времени суток! Хочу сделать дамп БД, но выходит такая ошибка

13:58:49 Dumping mydb (услуги) Running: mysqldump.exe
--defaults-file="C:\Users\D395~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1xihjt5h.cnf"  --host=localhost --port=3307 --default-character-set=utf8 --user=root --protocol=tcp "mydb" "услуги" Error executing task: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 33: invalid continuation byte
Operation failed with exitcode 6 Error executing task cannot access
local variable 'result' where it is not associated with a value
13:58:50 Export of
C:\Users\Игорь\OneDrive\Документы\dumps\Dump20241129 (7) has finished

Я так понимаю проблема в кодировке. Но я что только и не пробывал, ничего не помогает, помогите, пожалуйста. Как решить эту проблему?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с внятной формулировки заголовка.

Проблема решена. Я просто поменял все таблицы и столбцы на латиницу.
